# The Truth - Server Inventory And More

Tags: linux, server-room

All IT shops that reach a certain number of servers have some of form of inventory. In web operations , but not limited to, there is some incarnation of the Truth concept - a comprehensive database that describes all the equipment, relation between them and other information. An idealized Truth database can be asked any question about anything that's in the colo/server room and it will have some information about it. We use [Racktables](http://www.racktables.org) for that and have a bunch of scripts to generate configuration files for different things (nagios, dhcp, etc.).
We are also exploring some alternatives like a ldap directory server or some text files based thing (to keep it in subversion and have a history of changes).

What do you guys use ?

I know about GLPI and similar products but those are mostly for office LANs. We run a averaged sized colo (almost 1000 units) with linux servers.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet with reporting and the storeconfigs option can be used as a fully automatic answer for this.

If you're interested look at [Foreman](http://www.theforeman.org/) for a web interface to get started.

Answer (score 1):

HP Systems Insight Manager (SIM)